# createStartScripts change script name

Tags: gradle

In an attempt to follow the [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.application.tasks.CreateStartScripts.html), I added a task like this to my build.gradle file:

```
task createStartScripts(type: CreateStartScripts) {
  applicationName = 'dc-coverage-calculator'
}
```

I then executed

```
./gradlew clean installDist
```

at which point I expected to find a file at `build/install/dc-coverage-calculator/bin/dc-coverage-calculator`, but no files with *dc-coverage-calculator* were created anywhere the build folder.  Instead, gradle continued to use the default application name, based on the `mainClassName`.

I also tried removing the hyphens from the app name.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't work this way. You've added a new task whereas yo need to modify the existing one, which will be done this way:

```
startScripts {
   applicationName = 'dc-coverage-calculator'
}
```

Grab a demo [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/46457974).